# MYSQL Query error creating table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running on Mysql Server 5.7.13 and every time I try to create a table it throws this error:

> Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE content ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, page_id longtext, t' at line 5

Here is my query code:

```html
<?php
// Connect to MySQL
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '****');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
 $name = $_POST['name'];

// Make my_db the current database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($name, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
  // If we couldn't, then it either doesn't exist, or we can't see it.
$sql = "
  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $name;
  USE $name;
CREATE TABLE content
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  page_id longtext,
  title longtext,
  about longtext,
  content longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE details
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  website_name longtext,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE media
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  page_id longtext,
  post_id longtext,
  time longtext,
  date longtext,
  format longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE pages
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;";
var_dump($sql);
  if (mysql_query($sql, $link)) {
      echo "Database $name created successfully\n<br/>";
  } else {
      echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n<br/>";
  }

}

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Var dumb Results of Sql

/storage/www/cms/dbcreate.php:51:string

```
'USE socialnetwk;

CREATE TABLE content
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  page_id longtext,
  title longtext,
  about longtext,
  content longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE details
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  website_name longtext,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE media
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  page_id longtext,
  post_id longtext,
  time longtext,
  date longtext,
  format longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE pages
('... (length=600)
Database socialnetwk created successfully 
Error creating database: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE content ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, page_id longtext, t' at line 5
```

Comment: just as the error says. You can't go dropping pure SQL into PHP like that. That looks to me like you're not showing us the whole picture here.

Comment: Well creating the database works fine:
  $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $name;";

Comment: Tested code in sql - works fine, table created.

Comment: you've a quotes issue here `$sqlTwo = "USE $name;` <<< and PHP doesn't like that. That's why your code is failing here and error reporting would have been your friend today. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php that `;` is an end of statement character. Remove it. `$sqlTwo = "USE $name`

Comment: *Well creating the database works fine: `$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $name;";`* - Sure, because your quoting is correct.

Comment: Sql is fine, problem is elsewhere. Could you post the results of var_dump($sqlTwo); ?

Comment: @vincenth Updated my post

Comment: It would be good to have the entire output, not a truncated version.

Comment: Thats the entire output it gave me...

Comment: did you not try to remove the `;` in here yet? `$sqlTwo = "USE $name;` --- `$sqlTwo = "USE $name` - PHP sees that as an "end of statement" character http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php *"As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be **terminated** with a semicolon at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present."* @CasperRound

Comment: or removing `USE $name;` altogether. I've stuck around the question here longer than I usually do. So, unless I don't know what my suggestions did for you or not, then I can't be of any more help than I already tried. Ping me if you want, I've left the question. Good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, unless I am mistaken, the error is not on the php side. The error message comes from mysql. The semicolon would be considered as an end of statement if double quotes had been closed.

Comment: The USE should not be needed as you have _I assume_ connected to that database as part of the PHP connection information

Comment: I removed semicolon at the end of USE $name, didn't make a difference

Comment: @CasperRound add ini_set('html_errors', 0); at the start of your script, it should display the whole output.

Comment: No remove the WHOLE `USE $name;` line

Comment: Removed that line. How would it know which database to create the tables in now?

Comment: Because when you connect PHP to the database you tell it there in the `mysqli_connect()` or PDO dns string. Please tell me you are not using the deprecated `mysql_` API

Comment: I've updated my code, the whole idea of this script, is to create a database, then create tables within that database to be used later

Comment: And what is the result of this now

Comment: Error creating database: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE content ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, page_id longtext, t' at line 2

Comment: @CasperRound - you're trying to run multiple SQL commands in a single mysql_query call. You can't do that - the only way to run multiple commands in one call is by using the `mysqli_` library, and calling `mysqli_multi_query`

Answer (score 0):

I did a var_dump of $sql, it 's lacking semi-colon for the first two instructions (CREATE DATABASE and USE), it should be as follow :

```
$sql = "
  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $name;
  USE $name;
CREATE TABLE content
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  page_id longtext,
  title longtext,
  about longtext,
  content longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE details
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  website_name longtext,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE media
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  page_id longtext,
  post_id longtext,
  time longtext,
  date longtext,
  format longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE pages
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;";
```

Comment: It still throws the same error
Error creating database: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USE socialnetwk; CREATE TABLE content ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, page' at line 2

Comment: @CasperRound, could you please add ini_set('html_errors‌​', 0);  at the beginning of your script, and paste the output of var_dump($sql). Could you also give use the code where you connect to the db and execute the query ?

Comment: I've updated my post with the whole code. Added  ini_set('html_errors‌​‌​', 0);  to the start of the code yet its not affecting the output.

Comment: /storage/www/cms/dbcreate.php:50:string '
  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS socialnetwk;
  USE socialnetwk;
CREATE TABLE content
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  page_id longtext,
  title longtext,
  about longtext,
  content longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE details
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  website_name longtext,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE media
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  page_id longtext,
  post_id longtext,
  time longtext,
  date longtext,
  format longtext,
  PRIMARY K'... (length=645)

Comment: Use var_export($sql).

Comment: ' CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS socialnetwk; USE socialnetwk; CREATE TABLE content ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, page_id longtext, title longtext, about longtext, content longtext, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB; CREATE TABLE details ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, website_name longtext, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB; CREATE TABLE media ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, page_id longtext, post_id longtext, time longtext, date longtext, format longtext, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB; CREATE TABLE pages ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title longtext, PRIMARY KEY (id) )

Comment: ENGINE=InnoDB;'Error creating database: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USE socialnetwk; CREATE TABLE content ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, page' at line 2

Comment: Try putting your query right after the double quote, without any space or newline: "CREATE DATABASE... It's a long shot, but at this point I am running out of idea.